# The For loop in the code below stops after 4 iterations but if I run it again it will do another one. I would appreciate any advice as to why

Tags: for-loop

The loop stops after 4 iterations but when I run it again it does another 2 iterations and after that 1 at a time. The data can contain up to a hundred lines or more to process. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
Sub SASDAB()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("SAS&DAB")
        For i = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            If ws.Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 Then Exit For
            Sheets("Parts List").Activate
            With Range("B3").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='SAS&DAB'!R[-2]C[-1]"
            Range("B4").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='SAS&DAB'!R[-3]C[2]"
            Range("E5").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='SAS&DAB'!R[-4]C[-2]"
            Range("E6").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='SAS&DAB'!R[-5]C"
            Range("E117").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("$D$6:$D$845").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">0", _
                Operator:=xlAnd
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False
            Sheets("SAS&DAB").Select
            Rows("1:1").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            'Sheets("Parts List").Select
            End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are deleting selected rows with each pass.

```
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

This decreases the row count that drives the loop.

```
For i = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay but that fixed the problem